# Read string as command line argument C++

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line

I want to read a string and parse it in C++ to convert it to doubles from command line
and get each number in a vector

```
'1.1,2.3,3.4,4.6,5.8,6.9,7.8,8.0,9.9,10.11,11.67'

std::string tempInput;
tempInput = argv[1];
vector <double> example; 

std::vector< std::string > tokens;
while ( std::cin >> tempInput ) {
   example.push_back( <double>( tempInput )  );
}
```

So what would be the easiest way of doing this/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all of the commas with spaces:

```
std::string input = "1.1,2.3,3.4,4.6,5.8,6.9,7.8,8.0,9.9,10.11,11.67";

std::replace(input.begin(), input.end(), ',', ' ');

std::vector<double> result;
std::istringstream inputStream(input);

double value;
while (inputStream >> value)
    result.push_back(value);

inputStream >> std::ws;
if (!inputStream.eof())
    // Handle input error
```

Or, instead of the `while` loop, consider `std::istream_iterator`:

```
std::vector<double> result;
std::istringstream inputStream(input);

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(inputStream),
          std::istream_iterator<double>(),
          std::back_inserter(result));
```